# Задать фон для каждого символа

Tags: css

Есть у меня,например, скриптовая надпись,которая отображает день недели(или же 2+ слов),и мне нужно,используя чистый css и зная название селектора надписи,задать одинаковый фон для каждого символа (фоном выступит газоразрядный индикатор).Как это реализовать,и есть ли другие варианты?

```
<div class="value b-tooltipped" data-direction="top" original-title="сколько дней я уже не грущу">2 дня </div>
```

Как я уже говорил,есть возможность редактировать только css.

Comment: Хорошо бы увидеть ваш код, строение, пример....

Comment: Толку от этого мало,но код написал.

Comment: т.е  вам надо задать фон для каждого символа(цыфра и буквы по отдельности):   2 д н я ?

Comment: Да,именно так и нужно.

Comment: А доступы к HTML имеете ? точнее есть возможность обработать текст и каждый символ обернуть в <span></span> ?

Comment: Нет.Именно в этом случае нет,но если без доступа к нему никак,то для своего собственного проекта тоже было бы полезно знать решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `CSS` нет возможности обратиться к каждому символу в слове, но если есть возможность обработать текст и каждый символ обернуть в контейнер (например SPAN), то можно будет обратиться к каждому симвлу по отдельности.
 P.S если необходимо обратиться только к первому символу, можно использовать `::first-letter`

```css
.box span{
color:#fff;
padding:2px;
}

.box span:nth-of-type(1){
background:red;
}
.box span:nth-of-type(2){
background:blue;
}
.box span:nth-of-type(3){
background:grey;
}
.box span:nth-of-type(4){
background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<span>2</span>
<span>д</span>
<span>н</span>
<span>я</span>
</div>
```